# Django, Use style from database

Tags: python, css, django

In my database is style and I wanna used it in template, but I don't know how.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...

    body = models.TextField()  # HTML
    style = models.TextField()  # CSS

    # ...
```

views.py (I don't know Will it is useful)

```
# ...
# Context have to be get to every template extends form 'base.html'
base_context = {
    "category": Category.objects.all(),
}

# ...

def detail(request, slug, day, month, year):
    context = base_context.copy()
    context['post'] = Post.objects.get(slug=slug,
                                            created__day=day,
                                            created__month=month,
                                            created__year=year)
    return render(request, 'post/detail.html', context)

# ...
```

I tried:

```
{# ... #}

<style>
    {{ post.style }}
</style>

{# ... #}
```

(I know how to use styles saved in "static" directory)

I'm using django 2.1, and python 3.7.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions here should be self-contained. Please [edit] your question and pasted your `models.py` code into it. You can select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please only post relevant code. For example the `Category` is not related to your question. Neither are most of the imports. Also: you say that you want to use it in a template. What have you already tried? And what specifically didn't work? Did you get an error message maybe?

Comment: I also suspect the post might not be ending up in your template context. Django is nice and quiet when it fails to render missing things from context. Please post your view code as well. That's the missing piece between making your model show up in a template.

Comment: What is the result of the code you tried? It looks correct. Does it include the model's `style` content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so complicated but it requires a few steps. You need to:

1. create 2 new files (e.g. styling.py, post.css)
2. edit your model
3. edit your base template

styling.py

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


def get_style(post):
     return render_to_string('post.css', {'post': post})
```

post.css

```
{% if post.style %}
    {{ post.style }}
{% endif %}
```

or if you want to store just a single value in your style field e.g. `background-color`:

```
{% if post.style %}
    background-color: {{ post.style }}
{% endif %}
```

in your model.py

```
from styling import get_style

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    style = models.TextField()  # CSS
    ....

    def get_style_sheet(slef):
        return get_style(self)
```

in your base template add the following, but be sure that you have a `post` object in the context

base.html

```
<html>
<head>
    {% if post %}
    <style>
    {{ post.get_style_sheet()|safe }}
    </style>
    {% endif %}
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <style>
        {{ variable_name|safe }}
        </style>
    </head>
```

where variable_name is the variable containing css